How do I change the version of angular CLI
I'm trying to use the version 15.2.8 of Angular CLI, but I am struggling with the installation.
This is my actual version of angular:

To change the version I am starting the cmd with admin rights and launching the following commands:

The problem is that when I launch again ng v I still obtain the first image result. So I still have Angular CLI version 8.
¿How can I change my Angular CLI version properly?

You can follow this link https://update.angular.io/?v=8.1-15.0 , to upgrade your angular project, However i dont recommend to jump on v15. Your existing project's dependency might get affected, try to update step by step. Let me know how it goes.. :)

in order to change your angular cli version you should first try to uninstall the current version of cli with this command:
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli

then you install the version you want with this command for example you want version 12.0.0:
npm install -g @angular/cli@12.0.0


After running your command on my cmd out and in the Angular project. When I do "ng v" the version is still 8 and I have the following message: "Your global Angular CLI version (15.2.8) is greater than your local version (8.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used."

Because this is updating the global version of the Angular CLI not the project version, you have to update project version

You can actually update your Angular version with the help of the Angular Update Guide
Just select the starting version and the target version.
I suggest you update one version at the time by going in steps in case there are more than one major version of difference.
